# Where are the icons for the binding navigator located?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a BindingNavigator in C# winforms

I want to replace the navigation ToolStripButtons with my own BindableToolStripButtons

But I need to keep the same icons

When I drill into the image property of a navigation ToolStripButton I see that it is not a project resource file.

Where are these icons located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found it here:

[image]

It's in the form's resx file.

If you double click an icon, it gives a warning, and it tells you that you can't modify it directly, instead it creates a linked resource which you do can edit.

Comment: There doesnt seem to be an easy way to get to the desired icon by drilling into the icon property

Comment: What I do is to add my custom buttons (From VSimageGallery, internet, or photoshop) to the navigator and just call the navigator event handlers.

Comment: i like the ones that came with i the navigator I just copied them into my project resource file so I could get at them easily.